# Offered rate statistic in class-map shown only 0000 bps on interface

Tags: cisco, qos

I would like to monitor an offered rate on interface using class-map (ACL Match).

---

Config

```
Router#show policy-map interface port-channel 3

 Port-channel3 

  Service-policy input: GGC_ADSL

    Class-map: GGC_ADSL (match-all)
      0 packets, 0 bytes
      30 second offered rate 0000 bps
      Match: access-group name GGC_ADSL

    Class-map: GGC_ADSL_ALL (match-all)
      0 packets, 0 bytes
      30 second offered rate 0000 bps
      Match: access-group name GGC_ADSL_ALL

    Class-map: class-default (match-any)
      0 packets, 0 bytes
      30 second offered rate 0000 bps, drop rate 0000 bps
      Match: any 
        0 packets, 0 bytes
        30 second rate 0 bps


Router#show ip access-lists GGC_ADSL

Extended IP access list GGC_ADSL

    10 permit ip any 11.11.0.0 0.0.255.255

Router#show ip access-lists GGC_ADSL_ALL

Extended IP access list GGC_ADSL_ALL

    10 permit ip any any

Router#show policy-map GGC_ADSL

Policy Map GGC_ADSL
 Class GGC_ADSL
 Class GGC_ADSL_ALL



Router#show version 

Cisco IOS Software, s72033_rp Software (s72033_rp-ADVENTERPRISEK9_WAN-M), Version 12.2(33)SXI13, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)
```

---

Why the offered rated in every class is 0000 bps? Kindly give me suggestion.

This was the last configuration that an offered rate show by using the set DSCP bit action.

```
 #show policy-map interface port-channel 3
```

Service-policy input: GGC_ADSL

```
class-map: GGC_ADSL (match-all)
  Match: access-group name GGC_ADSL
  set dscp 10:
  Earl in slot 2 :
0 bytes
30 second offered rate 0 bps
aggregate-forwarded 0 bytes
  Earl in slot 3 :
0 bytes
30 second offered rate 0 bps
aggregate-forwarded 0 bytes
  Earl in slot 5 :
0 bytes
30 second offered rate 0 bps
aggregate-forwarded 0 bytes
  Earl in slot 7 :
7397272408547 bytes
30 second offered rate 1445423448 bps
aggregate-forwarded 7397272408547 bytes

Class-map: GGC_ADSL_ALL (match-all)
  0 packets, 0 bytes
  30 second offered rate 0000 bps
  Match: access-group name GGC_ADSL_ALL

Class-map: class-default (match-any)
  0 packets, 0 bytes
  30 second offered rate 0000 bps, drop rate 0000 bps
  Match: any 
    0 packets, 0 bytes
    30 second rate 0 bps


 #show policy-map GGC_ADSL
 Policy Map GGC_ADSL
   Class GGC_ADSL
     set dscp af11
   Class GGC_ADSL_ALL
```

My question is how to show the offered rate without using the DSCP bit action?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

From your configuration , it seems that you have not any initiated any traffic between the configured sources and destinations that match your access lists. The offered rate basically means volume of traffic that enters that class-map ( "offered" to this class ) . Since no traffic has hit the interface in the last polling interval of 30s, the offered and drop rate is 0 bps.

Comment: I have generate traffic from source 11.11.0.1 that match the condition in GGC_ADSL class. But the offered rate still 0000 bps and the last condition is permit any any. So If the first condition doesn't match , the offered rate of the  last condidtion should increase. But this issue all of the condition are not match.

Comment: After checking i found that if i set an action like set dscp bit to the policy the offered rate will show.



`Router#show policy-map GGC_ADSL

  Policy Map GGC_ADSL

    Class GGC_ADSL

      set dscp af11`



Is there any way to show the offered rate without using the dscp bit action ?

Comment: Try this. Remove the set dscp value or any other configuration of that sort.PING TO 11.11.0.1 ( your access list matches destination 11.11.0.0 subnet) with a repeat count of 10000. You should see the offered rate changing. "Offered rate" is calculated as the average rate over a polling interval(in this case it is  30s)

Comment: I have removed set dscp value and ping test from 11.11.0.1 but the offered rate still 0000 bps. In the same test if the class-map has an action (like set dscp or commit rate) the offered rate will be show. So im sure that the the condition matched but the offered rate was not show.

Comment: The ping should be TO 11.11.0.1 with a repeat count of 10000. Has this been done ?

Comment: Yes .  The offered rate was show only the class-map has an action.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this on my own lab and found the offered rate to change. Here is my configuration https://pastebin.com/J9qsDE04

Comment: I tried this on gns3 lab using cisco 7200 router and the offered rate change to. But it doesn't work on the production. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If the device is in production , I am not sure this would be right request to make but if you can , could you add the log keyword to your access list and generate traffic ? A ping with a high repeat count should suffice. I want to see traffic matching the ACL and then simultaneous output of sh policy-map <interface>. Please keep in mind , that log will make the packet punt to the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Maybe i should find the other way to solve this issue because the production can't ping with a high repeat.

Comment: Is the command "trust dscp" available as an action in a policy map, on that platform? 
That might help to make the service policy "do something" without actually doing anything, while still making it show the offered rates. 
If "trust dscp" or "trust ip dscp" is not available, you may also consider to "set ip dscp from dscp" using a 1:1 dscp-to-dscp map; again, just reading the dscp value from the original packet and re-applying it.